# Creating an Excel wrapper application using 0365 APIs

Tags: excel, wrapper, farpoint

Is it possible to create an app using the newest APIs for O365 that would provide a fully functional Excel spreadsheet, from a template, that would allow us to prevent access to SaveAs and other features? We've been able to create Excel wrapper apps like this using the Farpoint Spread controls I just wonder if apps of this nature are now possible using NAPA rather than 3rd party controls.